# Convert PDF to writeable form

Tags: pdf, conversion

What are the ways I can convert a PDF file, like this one: http://www.direct.gov.uk/prod_consum_dg/groups/dg_digitalassets/@dg/@en/@educ/documents/digitalasset/dg_184664.pdf to a file in writeable form?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a windows machine, you can download the freeware [PDF xChange](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer).

1. Select the Typewriter Tool, Under Tools;
2. Comment and Markup Tools  (also, you can select:

   1. View;
   2. Toolbars;
   3. Comment and Markup Toolbar for easier access to the Typewriter tool).

Answer (score 0):

There are several on-line converters these days.  Here's a a couple example sites that will convert PDFs to Word/RTF:

1. http://www.pdfonline.com/pdf2word/index.asp
2. http://www.pdftoword.com/

Keep in mind that you'll probably have to spend some time tweaking the converted file to get it to behave flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [PDFill PDF Editor](http://www.pdfill.com/index.html) for this.  You open the pdf and overlay the fields you want added onto the original pdf.